# TTY[1-6]: Lock screen after delay (like a screensaver)

Tags: command-line, console, tty

When using the virtual terminals on TTY 1-6 <sup>[*]</sup>, it's sometimes easy to forget to log out: The screen goes blank after a while, but I'm still logged in - no password required, anyone can use my account. (Or I switch to another TTY, and forget the other one...)

I'd like to have screensaver-like functionality that locks the terminal after 3 minutes, and then requires a password. How do I set this up?

---

<sup>[*] With TTY 1-6, I mean <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> (*no X Server*)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but I found you on google searching for the same question.

If you’re using bash, it’s no problem. Just use the environment-variable 'TMOUT' which is used by bash for a auto-logout (logout! not lock) in the given seconds.

You can just type ''TMOUT=5'' into any bash an see, what happens.

For configuration in my bashrc I’m using

```
# autologout on tty1-6 after 30 minutes
if [[ $(tty) =~ /dev\/tty[1-6] ]]; then TMOUT=1800; fi
```

so I don’t get logged out on a terminal-emulator which is normally on /dev/pty/# and already get locked by my screensaver as part of my desktop

Answer (score 5):

Implementing a screensaver that way for the TTYs is hard, as you cannot query the X server for the idle time.

If you discipline yourself, you can use the `vlock` command to explicitly lock a terminal.

A workaround for the timeout approach would be to ssh to localhost and let the ssh connection timeout take care of the rest. The timeout is specified under `LoginGraceTime` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and is 120 seconds by default.

If you run `exec ssh localhost`, you would be automatically logged out when the ssh connection times out. To keep your programs running past the timeout, you could run them via `screen`.

Comment: Both `vlock` and `exec ssh localhost` are **great** ideas (I will definitely use them)! You're right, it's probably hard to query the idle time without an X server. However, I wonder why the screen does go blank after some time (and wakes up on keypress)? So maybe the same "trigger" could be used to lock the screen automatically somehow?

Comment: I just found out, that the screen blanking (not the locking) can be adjusted by `setterm -blank [0-60]`, see [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/setterm.1.html).

Comment: @Egil `exec ssh localhost` does not logout automaticall after `LoginGraceTime` for me. I waited for about 8 minutes but nothing occured!